# Express.js and ejs directory of folder

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I want to insert this image which is located here: `images/image.png`
My main/start file is here: `server.js`
my routes are here: `routes/main.js`
my ejs file where I want to insert the image is here: `views/main/index.ejs`
What directory do I have to use to get the image?

I tried to go from the ejs file: `../../images/image.png`
I tried to go from my routes: `../images/image.png`
And I tried to go from the main file `./images/image.png` but nothing worked

`<img src="../../images/image.png" alt="Cuold not load image">`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0FFH.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't declared your "images" folder. Normally, javasript, CSS, images & etc are placed in a "public" folder. Add this codes to your server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

Create "public" folder and place "img" / "images" folder in it.

[image]

Then in your index.ejs file. Add this codes to retrieve image.

```
<img src="/images/image.png" alt="your image">
```